# Can't center image in css

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

My images won't center on my page. They are only centered on smartphones but not on laptops. How can I fix this?

```
@media only screen and (MIN-width:240px) {

img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto 0;
    margin-right: auto 0;
}   
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 40%;

}
.main-container {
min-height: 100vh;
/* will cover the 100% of viewport */
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 100px;
text-align: center;
/* height of your footer */
```

}

Comment: enclose the img tag inside a div and apply margin: 0px auto; to that div

Comment: My JsFiddle is working fine with those classes, could you show us your HTML?

Comment: Here is the HTML:  <html lang="da">
<link href="css/style.css" rel=stylesheet>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  <div class="main-container">   <img src="img/arosindgang2.JPG" alt=forside>   (The HTML that is related)

Comment: Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/ea630ou1/1/, it's working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex`. Wrap your image in `div` and use

`display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;`

for this `div`

Or use `margin: 0 auto` for image

Answer (score 0):

There is some syntax error in your CSS code. Try this:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width:240px) {
  img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: auto 0;
      margin-right: auto 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  img {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 40%;
  }

  .main-container {
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
 <html lang="da">  
   <meta charset="utf-8"> 
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
   <div class="main-container"> 
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=forside>
   </div>
</html>
```